# J. Tate's article on $p$-divisible groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, p-adic-groups, group-schemes

I have a question about a conclusion that J. Tate arrived at in his paper *$p$-Divisible Groups* (in: Springer T.A. (eds) Proceedings of a Conference on Local Fields. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg (1967) pp 158-183,[10.1007/978-3-642-87942-5_12](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-87942-5_12), [free pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.295.7566&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). On page 163 (§2) after defining what a $p$-divisible group is, i.e. for prime $p$ and integer $h \ge 0$ a $p$-divisible group $G$
over commutative ring $R$ of height $h$ is an inductive system

$$
G=(G_v,i_v), \quad v \ge 0
$$

where

1. $G_v$ is a finite group scheme over $R$ of order $p^{hv}$
2. for each $v \ge 0$,
   $$
   0 \to G_v \xrightarrow{i_v} G_{v+1} \xrightarrow{p^v} G_{v+1} 
   $$
   is exact (i.e., $G_v$ can be identified via $i_v$ with the kernel of multiplication
   by $p^v$ in $G_{v+1}$).

These axioms for ordinary abelian groups would imply

$$G_v=(\mathbb{Z}/p^v\mathbb{Z})^h$$

and $$G= \varinjlim G_v= (\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z})^h$$

> **Q:** why is $G_v=(\mathbb{Z}/p^v\mathbb{Z})^h$ true? I don't understand the first part.

Comment: For $v=1$, this is clear: $G_1$ is $p$-torsion by (2) and of order $p^h$ by (1), and hence has to be $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^h$. For $v>1$, proceed by induction.